# Find a pattern on an image with few training examples

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

We all know the <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> *"Find text..."* feature in text editors / browsers.
I'd like to study the available algorithms to do something similar on an image.

Example of UI/UX: let's say you have an [electronic schematic](http://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/images/electronic_die_circuit_diagram-2.png). You draw a rectangle around a diode, and then the algorithm will **automatically find all similar diodes on this image**.

In order to find a pattern on an image, I know (and have already used some of them) the classical tools:

- openCV `matchTemplate` (pros: works with a single training example, cons: doesn't support rotation or scaling)
- [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) (pros: I thing it accepts rotation and scaling,  cons: it requires 100s or 1000s  of training examples)

Which available algorithms are there which would do their best with 1 or 2 training examples only and accept scaling / rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Imo, yolo won't be useful in your case. It's great object detection model but it works with predefined classes - a trained model could automatically detect all types of diodes provided during training at once. So it's not designed for search.

I have some idea but I don't know how feasible that is. Assuming that all uploaded images will be some form of electronic scheme, it should be possible to train Region Proposal Network which outputs N chunks of image that likely contain a thing. Then when the user selects part of the image, the backend would only compare that selected part with N proposed regions and return only those with the highest score of similarity (for instance L2 distance).

You can read more about RPN in the Faster R-CNN paper - it's simple binary clarifier that evaluates multiple anchors at each position.